# What will the instruction "move #>$3,var" mean in 68k assembly?

Tags: assembly, 68000

What will the instruction   `move   #>$3,var` mean in 68k assembly ?

Comment: I would say a syntax error. The usage of `>` requires an assembler operand on the left side of it (to compare with the `$3` on the right side - a hexadecimal, `$`, value of `3` which, of course, is just `3`) but that is missing.

Comment: i'm not sure about this but ">" character might be representing the "high byte" or "high word" here. in "$3" case ">$3" equals to zero. but this ">" sign should be evaluated as a compiler level operator, not instruction level. "<" also means low byte/word in many assemblers. since i'm not sure about my answer, i write this as a supportive comment.

Comment: I was wondering about the advanced memory indirect addressing modes the 68020 (or 30?) have. But I am not familiar with those, even less when using AT&T syntax.

Comment: @Bleamer, unless this is intended as a kind of puzzle, can you tell us where you saw such a syntax?

Comment: It was part of legacy code implementation for a 68K based DSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The syntax `#>` is an operator to force long (immediate) addressing mode  in 68K and hence my instruction  `move #>$3,var` would mean - move the value $3 (0x03) to variable `var` forcing the long addressing mode in 68K assembly. I am not certain about the processors supporting this operation.

@drhirsch almost nailed it.